# Form elements not displaying in Jquery Fancybox on Internet Explorer 8 only

Tags: jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-8, fancybox, modal-dialog

I am implementing a modal style login window using Fancybox (which uses Jquery).  The modal box displays great in every browser except Internet Explorer 8.

In Internet Explorer 8, the form elements (labels, button and fields) are all missing.  I suspect it is something to do with the z-index positioning, but I cannot figure it out.

**The page in question is located at: http://d2-sandbox.parature.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptID=8210.**

Click on the **Sign In** button at the top right to see the issue.  Like I said, IE8 is the only browser with a problem.

Here is my call for Fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            scrolling : 'no',
            width : '500',
            height : '286',
            closeEffect: 'elastic',
            openEffect: 'fade'
        });});
```

Here's the code for the Login In button:

```
a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.chrishallahan.com/parature-small.html">
```

... and here is the code from my login form, which is an iframe:

```
<body>
<h1><span id="hide">suppport.kent.edu - Online Technology Help Center at Kent State University</span></h1>
<div id="login-form">
<form name="loginForm"  method="post" action="https://parature.kent.edu/default.aspx" target="_parent">
<label class="label">User Name:</label><input name="userid" class="searchbox" value="blank" size="30" type="text" /> <span class="email">@kent.edu</span><br />
<label class="label">Password:</label><input name="password" class="searchbox" value="blank" size="30" type="password" /><a class="forgot" href="https://login.kent.edu/ForgotPassword.aspx" target="_parent">Forgot Your Password?</a><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Log In" id="Button1" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="footer"><div id="text">Please log in with your FlashLine user name and password.</div></div>
```

Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: That's not making sense to me.  If the Login form is inside an `iframe`, I don't see how this can be `z-index` issue.  Does the [login form page](http://www.chrishallahan.com/parature-small.html) work properly in IE 8 by itself?

Comment: I looked at your stuff in IE 8.  The [login page](http://www.chrishallahan.com/parature-small.html) is rendering in `Quirks Mode` because [you're missing a valid `doctype` declaration](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chrishallahan.com%2Fparature-small.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  It may not make a difference but you'll want to fix that first.  Then if that still doesn't work, get rid of the iframe, and just put the HTML for the form into FancyBox.